# $_POST Wont get values

Tags: php

I am trying to print out the value of username text box on the page and this is my code as far as im aware this should work. I just seem to get an error called Use of undefined constant.

```
<html>

<head></head>
<body>




<form method = "post" action = "index.php">
Username:<input type = "text" name = "username">
<br>
<input type = "Submit" name = "Submit1">



<?php

$username1 = $_POST['username'];

print username1;



?>


</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: you forget the dollar sign ! `print $username1`

Answer (score 2):

`username1` should be `$username1`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
print username1;
```

with

```
print $username1;
```